# How to install "apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-mp3 libsndfile1 ffmpeg" on Windows

Tags: apt-get

I received this error. How do I install this repo. Thank you

> C:\Users\name>apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-mp3 libsndfile1 ffmpeg
>
> 'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users\name>

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Apt doesn't run on Windows. Are you in WSL perhaps? Your post needs a LOT more information before it is a question or can be answered.

Comment: @music2myear I actually doesn't know much about cmd or Python, I just wanted to set up with some help for this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ANonEntity/WhisperWithVAD/blob/main/WhisperWithVAD.ipynb) and to set up this model to local runtime rather than Colab's cloud. Under "Setup Whisper" it show me this error.

Comment: Once again, Apt doesn't run on Windows. Your question is clearly lacking significant context, information that is necessary for someone other than you to understand what is going on, which is your goal. Use the edit button and fix your question please.